# Java efficiency - child object referencing parent object

Tags: java, android, oop, garbage-collection

I'm new to java/garbage collected languages and I still am getting my head around what it means to have an object reference (because I'm told it's not a pointer?) so I'm pondering this question:

I have a parent/child object structure where the parent will have several lists of several children each...is there any inefficiency or any other reason not to have a pointer in each child back to it's parent?  In my prior language (Delphi) it was a simple pointer so not a problem at all.  Are there any considerations with this practice in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previous answers have stated, generally the GC is pretty good with clearing things up. Your primary concern will be things that persist once you leave an activity, hold onto context. This will cause your Activity to stay in memory because you have a reference to it that is not in it's parent child tree.

More on this [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be any issue here.  Technically yes, Java references are not pointers, but for most issues, you can think of them similarly.  Object references are integers pointing to locations in Java's heap.  Each additional place it's stored is therefore one additional integer.  Reasonably small, generally speaking.

You can (generally!) trust Java to do the right thing when it comes to object management, and shouldn't have to worry too much about garbage collection or the intricacies of how object references work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on object references! :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I know I'd say you'd be fine doing that. Java does a good job of cleaning up your garbage and I usually have a 'parent' field in children classes.

Comment: Thank you!  A friend confirmed this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be helpful if you read up on reference types as well - strong, weak, phantom and soft as it would be helpful.  Also, read up on how GC works (for different generations - young/survivor spaces & old generation), garbage collectors to use and GC parameters that you can specify.